# GTK / Glib: how to post message from GUI thread to worker thread?

Tags: gtk, glib

GTK is not thread-safe, but thread-aware - it can be used from multiple threads ensuring that global lock is used to protect GTK API calls. If i need to post a message from worker thread to GTK GUI thread i just call `gdk_threads_add_idle()` and specified callback will be called in GUI thread after some time.

But what is the easy way to do opposite thing - call specified callback from `non-GUI` thread as user clicks a button?

Comment: Could you provide more details? When you say callback do you mean signal handler of `G(tk)Object` to be triggered from `non-GUI` application? The function added through `gdk_thread_add_idle()` is triggered when there are no higher priority events pending in the event queue ... so "after some time" will vary before the function is called :)

Comment: @another I want my code to be executed in separate user clicks a GUI button. I don't really care if this `code` is a `C` function, GTK object method or whatever. Of course i can do it manually by writing a standard handler for GTK event, in this event putting some message into my own query and into separate thread i can use some code to wait for a message in queue and call some handler to process it. But it's a lot of code and less elegant than `gdk_threads_add_idle()` :)

Comment: When you say GUI button, is it safe to assume that it is a `GtkWidget`? AFAIK in GTK if you have to detect an event like user clicking a GUI button, it is through signalling mechanism; the event callback is triggered to indicate that the particular event has occurs (may not be instantaneous which you might be very well aware of). So for the "button click" you will have a event callback wherein you will do the required operations (blocking/non-blocking). Is you question pertaining to creation of threads in the event handler? Or do you want to find out about "button click" w/o the event handler?

Comment: @another I want the easiest way to execute `event callback that indicates that the particular event has occurs` in separate, non-GUI thread. I can do it manually with posting a message into custom queue that my thread will wait for, but it's a lot of code. So maybe GTK have some built-in way to propagate signal into non-gui thread.

Comment: With what limited knowledge I've, I'm not sure if you can do that, AFAIK the `event callback` will be called in the same GUI thread. There is a facility of creating new signal through `g_signal_new` and "emitting" them through `g_signal_emit` which will trigger the signal handler, but I think it is associated with `GObject` and not sure if it'll serve your purpose. Why do you need a custom queue? Cant non-GUI wait on conditional variables? In the `event handler` just signal the thread waiting on condition. `Glib Threads` (like other thread libraries) have these facilities

Comment: What I meant in previous comment was, if you choose to use `Glib Threads` in you non-GUI thread, use `g_cond_wait` for a conditional wait and in the `event callback` on button "clicked" in your GUI thread just signal the condition through `g_cond_signal` so that non-GUI thread proceeeds. There is no need for custom queues. You might already know about this or might have thought about this, but just in case you didn't I think this is possible :)

Comment: @another It's a lot of 'asynchronous' actions that are triggered from GUI and need to be processed in separate threads. Of course i can use conditional waits or queues, but this will be **a lot** of code :(. All i want to find is some way to reduce a number of code being written. After all, GTK have `gdk_thread_add_idle()` that allows to communicate from worker thread to GUI thread. So i'm wandering is it something as easy to communicate back from GUI thread to worker thread(s) :).

Comment: That is true... Sorry if this bugs you, but need a little more clarity to see if I can provide some info. When GUI thread is running, is worker thread already created & performing some operations or is worker thread spawned only when button click happens? If worker thread exists along with GUI thread, does it block or wait when GUI thread is running; if it is non-blocking how is GUI thread to request worker for operations? Is the GUI required to show some progress information?

Comment: Normally worker threads are started before GUI and just wait for a command to execute. Also, it's handy if worker thread is already here and will execute multiple commands one-after-another. Qt works this way - you just start a thread, than instruct Qt that specified object **lives** inside that thread - and viola, now all GUI events this object is subscribed to will be handled one-after-another in specified thread. **But** i'm open to other possibilities - of course, thread pool that spawn threads to handle GUI events is not very good, but C# somehow handles that in lots of apps :).

Comment: Ah ok. Unfortunately, I have not worked with Qt, but with little help of Google I found `moveToThread()` in Qt; I think this is the function/feature which you mentioned in your previous comment & are looking for GTK alternative for this. If that is the case then within my limited knowledge I'm not aware of such facility in GTK, but there is a facility of **thread pools** in `Glib` which might serve your purpose. It may be possible to execute your task in a separate thread pool.

Comment: Please check http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.29/glib-Thread-Pools.html : `... reusing already started threads seems like a good idea. And it indeed is, but implementing this can be tedious and error-prone. Therefore GLib provides thread pools for your convenience. An added advantage is, that the threads can be shared between the different subsystems of your program, when they are using GLib.`
`To create a new thread pool, you use g_thread_pool_new(). It is destroyed by g_thread_pool_free().
If you want to execute a certain task within a thread pool, you call g_thread_pool_push().` HTH

Comment: I've read all the comments and I must be missing something, what you want is a method to pass messages between your GUI and your worker thread, and you don't want to implement your own message queue, cause it's a lot of code ? right ?. Why not use this: ,[GAsyncQueue](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html), which is already implemented

Comment: Ummm I think option suggested by erick2red seems good for message passing b/w threads without much coding hassle... Its just that I haven't had a chance to use all the facilities provided by `GLib` and sadly haven't used `GAsyncQueue` so I was not aware... +1

Comment: GAsyncQueue is a good solution indeed. It's just more complicated compared to `gdk_thread_add_idle()`: i will need to somehow define message ID's and it will be a BIG switch inside a thread that will call appropriate function handle for a message :). For `gdk_thread_add_idle()` all this is free of charge :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from creating a new non-GUI loop with `g_main_loop_new`, run it from your non-GUI thread with `g_main_loop_run` and call `g_idle_add` from your GUI thread when needed.

Comment: How can i specify for `g_idle_add` that it must queue add for my own non-GUI loop and not the default loop of default GUI thread?

Comment: You must write your own version of `g_idle_add` that attaches it to the context of a different loop. In other words, write q copy of "this function":http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gmain.c#n4561 using something instead of `NULL`.